# How can I archive / export a Mac Catalyst .app of my iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

I am trying to export my iOS app as an .app file (not .ipa) so I can use it on my own machine like any other app. How can do this without first releasing to the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

Ah you can just double click the ipa and it will install the app in your applications folder if the catalyst target is available